# I keep getting undefined below

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to display the name of the file after the user has uploaded it. The file uploads successfully but in the javascript it keeps appending in the list  'undefined'. Why does it keep displaying 'undefined' and not the name of the file uploaded from the file input??:

Below is the code which displays the file name and message after uploading:

```
function stopImageUpload(success){

    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    localStorage["fname"] = files[0].name; //save the name for future use
}

$('.fileImage').bind('change', handleFileSelect, false);


      var result = '';
      if (success == 1){
  result = '<span class="msg">The file ('+localStorage["fname"]+') was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
    localStorage["fname"] = undefined; //remove the temporary variable

      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }

      return true;   
}
```

Below is form:

```
  <form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='stopImageUpload(this);' class='imageuploadform' >
    <p>Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' />
    <input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' />
    </p> 
    <ul class='list'></ul>
    </form>
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the function at runtime to find out what is available and that the name is successfully getting sent?

Comment: Well, first off it looks like you're defining a named function inside another one. Also, you're missing a curly brace somewhere.

Comment: I thought so too, @AlexMorales; but stopImageUpload contains the entire code section.

Comment: Why would you bind the input change event inside of the submit handler? It's never going to get called.

Comment: Ha, you are correct. It just looked a little strange to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [It keeps displaying undefined for file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174406/it-keeps-displaying-undefined-for-file-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try breaking apart your functions. Bind the change event outside of the function that handles the form submit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fileImage').bind('change', handleFileSelect, false);
});

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    localStorage["fname"] = files[0].name; //save the name for future use
}
function stopImageUpload(success){
      var result = '';
      if (success == 1){
  result = '<span class="msg">The file ('+localStorage["fname"]+') was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
    localStorage["fname"] = undefined; //remove the temporary variable

      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }

      return true;   
}
```

Comment: I have done the above but I am still getting undefined. THe file uploads successfully but I don't know why I keep getting undefined for file name?

Comment: look at the evt.target.files in firebug. console.log("files", evt.target.files); to see that name exists. you could also just do $(".fileImage").val() to get the file name as well.

Comment: I will do this and get back to you on what it outputs.